Highest temperature elastomer
I'm getting more into TIG welding these days & one thing I haven't quite mastered is feeding the filler with my less dominant hand (my left hand). My instructor taught me to simply use my middle finger & thumb to "slide" the filler. What I found more comfortable is to "roll & push" the filler between my thumb & index finger. He said what works for me is fine.
However, for me to execute this, I need more dexterity than what the typically bulky TIG welding gloves. Honestly, even with the simple "slide" method, I can hardly do it with these bulky gloves. So what I'm thinking is to get tight gloves & then coat it with a very high temperature elastomer. Gotta be an elastomer, or else it won't grab. The idea is whenever the coating gets burnt off, I will just reapply this elastomer.
The obvious elastomer of choice is silicone. What other liquid apply-able elastomers, that cures to a solid, do I have as an option?
Those Polyimides may not be rubbery, but they are heat resistant. Are they available in resin form?

There are high temperature silicones available in the auto parts stores. Have you rejected something like that for your objective? It's been red stuff for as long as I've seen it and advertised specifically for high temperature projects.

Somehow, I'm still holding off for some resin elastomer with ternary nitrogens, aromacity & strong hydrogen bonds.

Since you know what you are looking for (some resin elastomer with ternary nitrogens, aromacity & strong hydrogen bonds) why waste your time and ours by asking here?

Once you've taken those nasty thick thermally insulating gloves off & replaced them with nice thin thermally conductive ones, how are your fingertips going to feel about holding the hot filler rod?  Have you gone to a welding store and asked about thinner gloves?
